# QPainterPath intersections apha color

Tags: c++, qt

Can I force Qt to do alpha colors mixing for intersections within QPainterPath?
By default colors are not mixed: 
http://s23.postimg.org/obi80pe6h/scr.png

Comment: Have you tried playing with QPainters [composition modes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#composition-modes)?